# N+1 type queries?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the n+1 selects problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)

what is  N+1 type queries ?

i don't know what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing like N+1 type query

areyou talking about this -->
[What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)

Answer (score 2):

see here:

[What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem)

:)